# How to pronounce -est endings

Tags: pronunciation, spelling-pronunciations

Could you please confirm for me whether my understanding is correct about the pronunciation of the ending *-est* in superlative, for example: short*est*, farth*est*, bigg*est*,...

- *-est* is pronounced as /ɪst/ in American English  (ref: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UfV5Tq3YMGc)
- *-est* is pronounced as /ɛst/ in British English  (ref: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VXoiOzQCqxg )
- *-est* is pronounced as /əst/ when people don't pronounce seriously in casual situation. We use schwa sound /ə/ for unstressed syllables

However, if in American English, *-est* is really pronounced as /ɪst/, how American people pronounce the words **best**? I have *never* heard anyone pronounces the word **best** as  /bɪst/.

Comment: In your first video, *best* is clearly pronounced.

Comment: @Xanne But it seems that the teacher in this video said "that is not how it's pronounced" https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UfV5Tq3YMGc&t=48s , and she proposes to pronounce the ending *-est* as /ɪst/

Comment: No—look again. She’s saying the est in biggest is not pronounced like the est in best. It’s de-emphasized and more like ist.

Comment: @Xanne I see. So, in American English, the word **best** is exceptionally pronounced as /bɛst/ while other superlative words ending by *-est* is pronounced as /-ɪst/? Am I corect?

And pronuncing superlative words as /-ɛst/ is in British English (as in the second video)?

Comment: So it seems. Best, lest, guest, nest, all pretty close.

Comment: *Best* isn't *b* + *est*. It's its own word. *Good* and *well* (which *best* is now considered the superlative of—though, if I recall correctly, the etymology is more complicated than that) are irregularly inflected.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In English, the letters *est* is generally pronounced /ɛst/ in a stressed syllable. It's only in unstressed syllables that it's reduced to /ɪst/ or /əst/, depending on the speaker's dialect (most often /ɪst/ in British English and /əst/ in American or Australian English).

So the words *best, jest, test, vest, arrest, protest, invest,* are all pronounced /ɛst/.

And the words *shortest, biggest, earnest, forest* are all pronounced /ɪst/ or /əst/.

Comment: I see. Thank you for your clear answer!

Answer (score 6):

The suffix *-est* is traditionally pronounced /ɪst/ in standard Southern British English, but it is being replaced by /əst/. See [Lindsey (2019: 39–40)](https://books.google.com/books?id=6nSKDwAAQBAJ&pg=PA39).

North American English doesn't have the contrast between /ə/ and /ɪ/ in unstressed syllables to begin with (so that *Lenin* and *Lennon* are homophonous, and *hammock* and *dynamic* rhyme), while the merged vowel usually has a quality higher than [ə] when it neither begins nor ends a word, which is often represented as [ɨ] or [ɪ] ([Flemming & Johnson 2007](http://web.mit.edu/flemming/www/paper/rosasroses.pdf)). The merged vowel is usually represented phonemically as /ə/, but before palato-alveolar and velar consonants (/ʃ, tʃ, dʒ, k, ɡ, ŋ/) and in prefixes like *re-, de-*, it is often represented as /ɪ/ ([Wells 2000: xv](https://archive.org/details/longman-pronunciation-dictionary/page/n17/mode/1up)).

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. It's very clear.
I have a question, in the second Youtube video of my question ( https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VXoiOzQCqxg&t=430s  , *Fatima's house is the biggest* ), the teacher read many times (for example, at 7 minutes 10 seconds) /-ɛst/. Perhaps she has a different accent that is used somewhere in the world? Or perhaps indeed she said / **ɪ**st/ or / **ə**st/ but my ears cannot capture the sound yes and so I thought she said / **ɛ**st/?

Comment: The pronunciation of *-est* in the video sounds like [ɪ] to me. That doesn't necessarily mean it should be identified phonemically as /ɪ/ rather than as /ə/, since younger speakers of British English might lack the contrast, but no, it doesn't sound like /ɛ/.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer!

Comment: A speaker has the contrast between /ə/ and /ɪ/ in unstressed syllables exactly when they don't have the weak vowel merger. The [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phonological_history_of_English_close_front_vowels#Weak_vowel_merger) on this merger says that it is widespread in Australia, it is common in America, and is not present in RP. This means that there are a lot of Americans who don't have it. You are making the common mistake of assuming that all Americans speak the same.

Comment: @PeterShor Flemming & Johnson say the "distinction is not made in the American accents that we are familiar with" (p. 95), and I'm not familiar with one either. Can you name one?

Comment: @Nardog: The *American Heritage* dictionary represents pronunciations without the weak vowel merger, as can be seen from their entries for [ferret](https://www.ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=ferret&submit.x=39&submit.y=14) and [parrot](https://www.ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=parrot&submit.x=61&submit.y=23). So presumably, they don't think it's widespread enough yet to change their pronunciation (and they do follow changes in American pronunciation; in their fifth edition—2011—they dropped the distinction between the vowels in *force* and *north*).